# How to block some users to access wamp/www/myproject folder's json files

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have a project which has a folder and contains json files.

```
     ->   WAMP/www/MyProject  -> JSON_Folder -> one.json, two.json, three.json, four.json, five.json etc.
```

Now I have a task : Have multiple users – Super User/Main User/Second User/Student.

```
     -  Depends on the users permission one could see the json files.
     -  Super User can see all the json files
     -  Main User could see Main User files and Second user files and student user files.
     -  Second user could only see Second user files and Student files.
     -  Student user could only see Student User files.
```

I could also create Super_User_Folder, Main_User_Folder,Second_User_Folder, Student_User_Folder under JSON_folder. I am going to create user login in page. When the user login - depends on the user they could see the json files. Don't know. 
How could I achieve this? I could create users in MYSQL also for user permissions. But how I could allow not to access MyProject’s JSON folder?  Good suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch "\.json$">
AuthName "Dialog prompt"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /etc/apache/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
require user SuperUser
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "^one\.json$">
AuthName "Dialog prompt"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /etc/apache/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
require user StudentUser1
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "^two\.json$">
AuthName "Dialog prompt"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /etc/apache/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
require user StudentUser2
</FilesMatch>
```

Restrict by folders

```
<Location /student1>
Options Indexes
  AuthType basic
  AuthName "login info required"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache/.htpasswdstudent1
<RequireAll>
  Require all granted
</RequireAll>
</Location>
```

You can even limit also by group

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. I am reading more about FilesMatch and htaccess. And I will accept this as an answer after I use this concept. Thank you again for your immediate reply :)

Comment: question: I feel instead of FilesMatch, Directory match would be better. I need to create Super_User_Folder, Main_User_Folder, Second_User_Folder, Student_User_Folder under JSON_Folder. Because the application creates many json files from many different users(folder name users). I will not the what user what file they created to give the password to access. If it's a folder then they could create and see their files. Is there any DirectoryMatch? or any idea?